Swiping up from the bottom of the screen (to switch apps) unintentionally triggers another object's DragGesture in SwiftUI, iOS
This is about SwiftUI.
I have an object with a DragGesture attached to it and this object is positioned at the very bottom of the screen in iOS – just above the safe area with the app switcher handle. The drag gesture should only be triggered when dragging commences from inside of the object + the area of a few pixels around it, that's expected. It correctly doesn't get triggered when dragging commences from outside of the object (left, right, top side) but when I try to switch apps by swiping up on the app switcher handle at the bottom of the screen the drag gesture gets triggered. Please see the code and the animation. How do I get rid of this behavior?
I searched for an answer to this everywhere but to no avail. I tried to specifically define the area that should only respond to the gesture but also to no avail. Swiping up from the app switcher handle does something which makes iOS think that after the finger leaves the safe area the user tapped the object and commenced the dragging from inside of it, thus triggering the gesture – even though they never lifted the finger after touching the screen. The gesture shouldn't be triggered by swiping up, it's an unwanted behavior.
Thank you for your help.
https://i.sstatic.net/4hvgubwL.gif
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var offset = CGSize.zero
    @State var color = Color.green
    
    var body: some View {
        Spacer()
        Circle()
            .fill(color)
            .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
            .offset(offset)
            .gesture (
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onChanged { value in
                        color = .red
                        offset = value.translation }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        color = .green
                        offset = .zero
                    }
            )
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}```


You can try to maintain the state by setting a Bool on onAppear() and onDisappear to make sure the app is currently active.

The gesture gets triggered before the app state changes. Not to mention that it gets triggered even if the app switcher is not activated – when I tap the very app switcher handle and try to drag it up. It's visible in the animation. One trigger event happens with the app state being changed and one happens without it.
